# Satellites or UFOs?

Tags: observational-astronomy, star, light, satellite, frame-of-reference

Last night in Greenville MI at around 9:15pm-9:25pm (I don't know the exact time) I saw what appeared to be a satellite appear and disappear and then a few seconds later another possible satellite appear in the same spot and then disappear. And then a few seconds later another possible satellite appear in the same spot and then disappear.  This event happened for a few minutes. I am not sure what it was... What do you think?

Comment: What were weather conditions like, for example, was it clear, cloudy, partly cloudy? Approximately what position in the sky did you see the objects? Which direction were you facing?

Comment: These are going to be satellites.  Satellites are launched in very large groups these days.  What you saw was almost certainly a string of recently-released satellites which will likely form part of an internet-providing constellation of satellites.  If you can gather the info Greg Burghardt is asking about you can find out exactly which satellites you saw on various sites on the Web.  It's the new reality of our skies.

Comment: Most likely a Starlink chain of recently launched satellites.  This site can help in identifying them: https://heavens-above.com/

Comment: To double check, "last night" means Thursday night, September 22, 2022? Is "9:15pm-9:25pm" in EDT? (Eastern Daylight Time, UTC-4)